# woocommerce breadcrumbs show parent and sub categories?

Tags: woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I'm having a really hard time with this... essentially I just want to display breadcrumbs on the product category pages in woocommerce so that it shows the main category and sub categories. Hoping some smart kind soul can help me :)

This normally could be done easily with the following code:

```
 <?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>
```

However, I'm using a purchased theme with woocommerce integrated, so it doesn't have that function and I tried to integrate it but no luck.

So, I found someone who had the same issue and made my own breadcrumbs for prordu.  Which works, but I just want the product category to show ONLY the main category and sub category each product have. The code shows ALL categories and sub categories, not just the one I want to display.

```
 <?php
 $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
 $orderby      = 'name';  
 $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
 $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
 $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
 $title        = '';  
 $empty        = 0;
 $args = array(
 'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
 'orderby'      => $orderby,
 'show_count'   => $show_count,
 'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
 'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
 'title_li'     => $title,
 'hide_empty'   => $empty
 );
 ?>
 <?php $all_categories = get_categories( $args );
 //print_r($all_categories);
 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
 //print_r($cat);
 if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
    $category_id = $cat->term_id;

 ?>      

  <?php       

    echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>'; ?>


    <?php
    $args2 = array(
      'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
      'child_of'     => 0,
      'parent'       => $category_id,
      'orderby'      => $orderby,
      'show_count'   => $show_count,
      'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
      'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
      'title_li'     => $title,
      'hide_empty'   => $empty
    );
    $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
    if($sub_cats) {
        foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
            echo  $sub_category->name ;
        }

    } ?>



<?php }     
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems like you're missing some code above what you posted where it's looping through all of the categories (and judging by the two `}` at the bottom).  Can you post the code that goes above the existing?

Comment: Still trying to find a solution for this. I edited the code above, essentially I want it to just be like Home > Bottoms > Tights > Leggings for example.  This is a page that demonstrates what I want to do, but this person only has code relevant to their theme... http://support.jawtemplates.com/goodstore/web/?p=394  Can some kind soul please help?